# List entries on multiple criterias, paginated

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by, limit

I need your help in the following situation:

I have a table that looks like this

```
----------------------------
| id | order | highlighted |
----------------------------
|  1 |   5   |      1      |
----------------------------
|  2 |   7   |      1      |
----------------------------
|  3 |   0   |      0      |
----------------------------
|  4 |   0   |      0      |
----------------------------
|  5 |   9   |      1      |
----------------------------
|        *and so on*       |
----------------------------
```

- `id` is INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT
- `order` is INT(11)
- `highlighted` is INT(11) and contains only '1' or '0' values

I would like to sort those entries, in one query, like this:

- first display all rows that have `highlighted` = '1' ordered by `order` desc
- following are the rows that have `highlighted` = '0' ordered by `id` desc
- the obtained list should be paginated (`limit 30, 10` - as an example, it would be Page 3 with 10 items per page)

The result should be:

```
----------------------------
| id | order | highlighted |
----------------------------
|  5 |   9   |      1      |
----------------------------
|  2 |   7   |      1      |
----------------------------
|  1 |   5   |      1      |
----------------------------
|  4 |   0   |      0      |
----------------------------
|  3 |   0   |      0      |
----------------------------
|        *and so on*       |
----------------------------
```

Any ideas?
Thank you in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.order, a.highlighted 
FROM tableA a
ORDER BY a.highlighted DESC, 
        (CASE WHEN a.highlighted = 1 THEN a.order ELSE a.id END) DESC
LIMIT 30, 10;
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! One question: how will the query look if, besides those columns (that are used for sorting), there are a few others (like `name`, `title`, `alias` and so on - let's say `*`) that I need?

Comment: Your query will give me the values from the columns `id`, `order` and `highlighted` but I need also the values from the other columns present in that table (like `name`, `title`, `alias` and so on). I'm sorry that my table example did not include them so that it would be clear the first time :(

Answer (score 0):

try below:

```
    select * from 
    (
    select * from tableA where highlighted = 1 Order By order desc    
    UNION     
    select * from tableA where highlighted = 0 Order By id desc
     )alias    LIMIT 30, 10
```

Comment: @punctweb, No It was alias name , I have changed it